# branch io integration with Adobe air app issue

Tags: air, adobe, branch.io

Our iOS app is live in iTunes, and we want to integrate it with Branch io. We can build the ipa for testing, but when we try to "Export Release Build", the Flash Builder 4.6 will hang.

This is the branch io guide that we are following:
https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/sdk-integration-guide/guide/adobe/

We just followed the steps, and put in the stuff up to step 4, where we called
branch.init() in the main class. The setting in branch io is setup ok.

here are the codes, (just copied from branch io's website)

```
// Then create a Branch instance:
var branch:Branch = new Branch();

// Register two events before initializing the SDK:
branch.addEventListener(BranchEvent.INIT_FAILED, initFailed);
branch.addEventListener(BranchEvent.INIT_SUCCESSED, initSuccessed);

private function initFailed(bEvt:BranchEvent):void {
    trace("BranchEvent.INIT_FAILED", bEvt.informations);
}

private function initSuccessed(bEvt:BranchEvent):void {
    trace("BranchEvent.INIT_SUCCESSED", bEvt.informations);

    // params are the deep linked params associated with the link that the user clicked before showing up
    // params will be empty if no data found
    var referringParams:Object = JSON.parse(bEvt.informations);

    //trace(referringParams.user);
}

// Initialize the SDK:
branch.init();
```

Any clues?